Ajax sending without return due to possible obfuscation in a subsequent sending from the server to an external website
From the client I send an Ajax request to the server expecting a return.
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RespuestaajaxL.aspx/RespuestaajTask",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{"parametro":"funcion","valor":"ActualizarArchivoDrive","tabla":"' + datosserver.nombrearchivo + '","campo":"' + datosserver.extensionarchivo + '","criterio":"' + datosserver.nombrearchivosinext + '","v1":"' + datosserver.extensionarchivoO + '","v2":"' + datosserver.idFile + '","v3":"' + datosserver.idFolder + '","v4":"","v5":"","v6":"","v7":"","v8":""}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (devolucion) {
            if (devolucion.d) {
                alert("Actualizado el archivo en Drive");
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("No hubo respuesta desde el servidor. Prueba otra vez.");
        }
    });

The call is successful. In a routine already on the server, an update is performed of a file located in Google Drive. This update is carried out successfully but the response is not returned to the client. The process returns nothing to the client.
I have checked by reducing the code to the minimum, and then adding a new line back each time. The return to the client was always produced except when the line was reached:
var result = await updateRequest.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

From a module from which I receive the Ajax request I execute the function that updates the file in Drive.
 public static Task<string> RespuestaajTask(string parametro, string valor, string tabla, string campo, string criterio, string v1,
            string v2, string v3, string v4, string v5, string v6, string v7, string v8)
        {
            try
            {
                if (parametro == "funcion")
                {
                    if (valor == "ActualizarArchivoDrive")
                    {
                        return Cp.ActualizarArchivoDrive(tabla, campo, criterio, v1, v2, v3);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception exc) {
                string st = exc.Message;
            }
            return null;
        }

The update of the Google Drive file was carried out using the following method:
public async Task<string> ActualizarArchivoDrive(string nombrefile, string extension, string nombrefilesinext, string extensionO, string idFile, string idFolder)
        {
            try
            {
                string extGuardar = (extension != extensionO ? "jpg" : extensionO);
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService ds = CodigoGeneral.Globales.gds;
                string filePath = (string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + nombrefilesinext + "." + extGuardar;
              
                var updateFileBody = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
                {
                    Name = nombrefile
                };
               
    await Ue(filePath, idFile, "image/jpeg", updateFileBody, ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string ss = ee.Message;
            }
            return "Finalizado";
}

As you can see, the previous method calls the following method with await:
public async Task Ue(string filePath, string fileId, string MIME, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File updateFileBody, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService ds)
            {
                try
                {   
    
                    using (var uploadStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    
                    {
                        // Update the file id, with new metadata and stream.
                        var updateRequest = ds.Files.Update(updateFileBody, fileId, uploadStream, MIME);
                        var result = await updateRequest.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);    
                        
                        uploadStream.Flush();
                        uploadStream.Close();
                        
                    }
                } catch (Exception EE)
                {
                    string h = EE.Message;
                }
            }

As it seems to me, it may be happening that after the update call is made through the drive.service established with Google Drive with updateRequest the process stops on my site and loses the ability to pick up the thread. But I have no idea why. The update occurs but I need to receive the return on the client because after the thread is lost the application becomes inactive and does not respond to any events.
The outline of the process described is as follows:

I edit to add screenshots of the network tool related to the request Ajax


Edited to comment on the result of a test that limits the problem.
I've run the update method from the server, suppressing the initial Ajax send from the client.
An error still occurs after successfully updating. The error message is: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Reference to object not set as an instance of an object.'"


If a problem is occcuring in the C# code, things like catch (Exception ee)             {                 string ss = ee.Message;             } will be obscuring any exceptions. You catch the exception, you assign its message to a string and then....you do nothing with it. No output, no  logging, nothing. So if there's problem, you've just discarded all the useful information which might help you to debug it. It's unclear what you expected this catch block to achieve. Start by removing the try/catch and see if any errors then occur, which you can use to help you understand the issue.

Hello A. Dyson! In that try catch I place a breakpoint and query the value of the string with the error message. But no error occurs, that is, the try catch does not come into action.

Ok. So if you put breakpoints in other places, where does the code reach? Does it execute all the instructions you expect it to? Do the relevant variables have all the values you expected them to?

I have checked all the routines with breakpoints and no errors occur. The file in Drive is updated correctly, but once there the asp.net application goes dead. It does not return any error nor is it returned to the client that sent the Ajax request.

The method that calls the function that updates the file has a return that expects a string. However that method public async Task ActualizarArchivoDrive returns Task. That may be the problem. I don't know how to make that method receive a string if the update method actually returns a Task

Edited the question again

The execution of the process does not pass from the next line.
return Cp.ActualizarArchivoDrive(tabla, campo, criterio, v1, v2, v3);

Thanks. Have you tried it like this? if (valor == "ActualizarArchivoDrive") { string response = await Cp.ActualizarArchivoDrive(tabla, campo, criterio, v1, v2, v3); return response; }

I try but no match. Cp.ActualizarArchivoDrive(tabla, campo, criterio, v1, v2, v3); expects string but the executed method returns Task.

Strange. Can I check, is public static Task<string> RespuestaajTaskv your actual code? Should it not be public static async Task<string> RespuestaajTask, since you are returning a task there.

yes I have tried as Task with async but it doesn't work either.
It must be a public static string because that is what is expected in return from the client. The problem is that it should return an error but it doesn't go past that line.

Ok. So then you can't use await where I suggested because the RespuestaajTaskv method isn't async. Therefore I tried to make a minimal demo to pinpoint the issue. With the correct values provided, the outer code should work, in the sense of returning a basic string, even if an exception occurs - demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rSNMFZ .  So I'd guess perhaps the issue is something in the Ue function, maybe.

Or, if you don't pass the right values into RespuestaajTask, you should get an exception because in that case, ActualizarArchivoDrive is not executed, and instead the RespuestaajTask`` method returns nullinstead of a populatedTask- demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ykMcsR . It's hard to tell exactly what is going on for you. Or maybe there's an async method call somewhere that you've forgotten toawait`, and it's getting stuck in there somewhere. So these are just some things for you to investigate further.

The values ​​passed are correct and the following two methods are executed. In fact the file update in Drive is successful. But that line does not continue. And the application gets stuck without returning any error. I guess it's a problem when passing Task to a method that expects Task. Also, if I set it to expect string, the same happens

I guess it's a problem when passing Task to a method that expects Task<string>...you aren't doing that. And my demo proves that it can work. So probably, as I said, it's stuck more internally somewhere. Start with a super-minimal demo like I showed, where ActualizarArchivoDrive just returns a string, without doing any other work, and see if it still fails or not. Plug that into your $.ajax request and see what happens. If everything is ok, then build it back into what you want, one step at a time, until it stops working again. That will help you to narrow down the issue better.

Yes, when the method returns only a string it works and the return occurs. But the update in Drive doesn't happen. In order for string to be returned, the update cannot be executed asynchronously. Must be Task. And when Task is returned, the line is stuck. Thanks for your help. I will try your demonstration and put the results in the question.

Yes, when the method returns only a string it works ...I think maybe you misunderstood what I meant. In my demo I still used Task, if you notice. You should reduce ActualizarArchivoDrive to just public async Task<string> ActualizarArchivoDrive(string nombrefile, string extension, string nombrefilesinext, string extensionO, string idFile, string idFolder)  { return "Finalizado"; } and see if you can get the right output. If that's ok, then start adding back the other code, one line at a time, until things start to go wrong again.

ok I will try that as you told me. Thank you very much

No problem. Be sure to remove all the try/catch blocks as well when testing, so that errors are not accidentally hidden.

I have checked by adding a new line each time. The return to the client was always produced except when the line was reached: var result = await updateRequest.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None); It's just when it's sent to Google Drive. It looks like you don't get a return from Google Drive, but the file update operation happens. The problem is that it kills the application

So the code just hangs there? Maybe it times out due to the size of the upload?? I notice that you have assigned var result but you don't check its value or use it for anything - is that deliberate? Also I forgot to ask - do you see anything in the browser's Console or Network tool indicating what happens to the ajax request, when this problem occurs?

No error appears in the console.
When it comes to checking the result value, I have ignored it for the moment because the operation takes place in Google Drive. It should go on.

Yes but it's useful to see if the HTTP request returns with 200 OK status, or something else, and if there's anything in the response body. Or whether it ends up timing out, or what. The more information we have, the better.

Can you try moving your var updateFileBody = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File() {Name = nombrefile;} into your Ue function? Instead of passing updateFileBody as a parameter to Ue, try initializing it in the Ue function itself.

I understand A. Dyson. I have set a breakpoint to check the value of result but it is impossible to see it because it does not get a return value. That is the last line of code that is processed and then returns to the state of this unknown error.

I have done what dasfad says SoftDveloper but the operation is identical. The same problem continues. Thank you!

That is the last line of code that is processed and then returns to the state of this unknown error...ok, but then the AJAX call must either complete, or fail (perhaps due to timeout). So you must be getting something in the Network tool as the result of the call - even if it's just a HTTP response code with no content

@SoftwareDveloper try moving your var updateFileBody = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File() {Name = nombrefile;} into your Ue function what difference do you expect that would that make? The code is functionally identical in both cases. It's just an object being passed around.

To apply what SoftwareDveloper proposed I had to do it since that variable is necessary. I passed it as a parameter from one method to the other. In my opinion, I don't think the problem comes from the processing of that variable. Everything works the same.

No error appears in the browser console. You also don't receive an error in response to the Ajax call. It would show the alert that I have met in error: function (req, status, error)

It may not be possible to make an Ajax call to the server and then make a call to an external site like Google Drive. Is that possible?

No error appears in the browser console...OK.. what about your observations of the Network tool?

It may not be possible to make an Ajax call to the server and then make a call to an external site...there's no reason  in principle why that shouldn't be possible. But the behaviour here sounds odd. By the way what version of .NET are you using?

About network tool: I don't use any network tool. I see that it could be of great help to me although I have never used it-. Uso .NET Framework 4.7.2.

The Network tool is right there in your browser's Developer Tools, a couple of tabs along  from the Console. You can use it to see your AJAX request when it happens, and see exactly what response you got from the server. It shows you the whole HTTP request and response, including status code, headers and body. If you're working with web applications, and especially with AJAX, you need to know how to use it.

Thank you. It is information very usefull.

I have added the capture network tool to the question

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I have the solution
The code example I referenced uses "await using". However, that feature does not exist in c# 5. I am using only "using". In that case the asynchronous method UploadAsync() causes the problem. It is not expected and a NullReferenceException is thrown. I use the synchronous Update() method instead. And now the return from Google Drive does occur and the ASP.NET application does not stop.
I've gathered all the code into a single method since I'm not using await to wait for the second method. The code looks like this:
 public async Task<string> ActualizarArchivoDrive(string nombrefile, string extension, string nombrefilesinext, string extensionO, string idFile, string idFolder)
       

  {
                    
    string extGuardar = (extension != extensionO ? "jpg" : extensionO);
                        
    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService ds = CodigoGeneral.Globales.gds;
    
    string filePath = (string)HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "google/archivoseditados/" + nombrefilesinext + "." + extGuardar;  
       

 var updateFileBody = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
               {
                Name = nombrefile,
               };
    FileStream uploadStream = 
                    new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (uploadStream)
  {
//// Update the file id, with new metadata and stream.
                       
    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload updateRequest = 
    new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload(ds, updateFileBody, idFile, uploadStream, "image/jpeg");
                               
 var result = updateRequest.Upload();               

 if (result.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)

   {
     return "Finalizado";
   }
  }
}

